# Десериализация полученных POST-запросом json-данных в FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, post, fastapi

Я использую FastApi (запуск через uvicorn) для приема простеньких `json`, но я не знаю как их перегнать в обычный текст, который я хочу загнать в sqlite3 (нужна именно строка со всеми параметрами в ней, а не отдельные столбцы). Базовая модель следующая:

```
class UserIn(BaseModel):
    time: str
    login: str
    password: str
    
@app.post("/user/", user=UserIn)
```

Дальше представлены способы, которыми я пытался пользоваться:

Первый вариант, пришедший мне в голову:

```
userjson = json.dumps(json.loads(user.time + user.login + user.password))
print(userjson)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)

Второй вариант:

```
print(user.json())

**not valid dict**
```

Отправляю POST через:

```
print(requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/', json={'time': 'TUE 28 JAN 198', 'login': 'jss', 'password': '12rwrfwa'}))
```

Comment: а что декорирует собой @app.post("/user/", user=UserIn)? там должна быть функция, возвращающая объект user...

Comment: Можно пожалуйста объяснить? Я не разбираюсь в таких вопросах и поэтому туплю

Comment: попробую )) для начала:  какие данные вы хотите "загнать в sqlite3" и что печатает print(requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/', json={'time': 'TUE 28 JAN 198', 'login': 'jss', 'password': '12rwrfwa'})) ?

Comment: Принтит ошибку/код который в отсылает uvicorn в ответ на post

Answer (score 0):

Хм.. А попробуй для начала вот так

```
class UserIn(BaseModel):
    time: str
    login: str
    password: str


userjson = json.dumps(user.dict())
```

P.S. Напомню, хранить пароли в открытом виде это небезопасно.

Comment: Так же, если чем-то поможет: ошибка **raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for UserIn
response
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)**

Сервер получает: **{"time":"12w12","login":"jss","password":"12rwrfwa"}**